# Test method " " System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am receiving this exception:

Test method OnlineBankingTests.ConnectNativeSmokeTest.CNLoginTests.VerifyLoginNoBlankPwd threw exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:
CNLoginPage.PasswordRequired() line 577
CNLoginTests.VerifyLoginNoBlankPwd() line 78

But, to me it looks like the object is referenced... I am a little lost.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("CNSmoke")]
    public void VerifyLoginNoBlankPwd()
    {
        CanRun();

        // Arrange
        var baseUrl = Settings.ConnectNativeURL;

        var loginPage = new CNLoginPage(ConnectNativeDriver); // Isnt it creating a reference here to the class that contains the PasswordRequired() method??

        // Verify Password is Required
        loginPage.GoTo(baseUrl);
        loginPage.PasswordRequired(); // Line 78
        Assert.IsTrue(
            loginPage.IsBlankPasswordErrorSuccessful(),
            "Leaving Password blank didn't produce expected error.");
    }
```

---

```
public class CNLoginPage
{

    public void PasswordRequired()
    {
        var userId = _driver.GetElementByCssSelector("#username");
        userId.SendKeys("TESTER"); // Line 577

        var password = _driver.GetElementByCssSelector("#password");
        password.SendKeys(" ");

        var enter = _driver.GetElementByCssSelector("#AutomatedTesting-loginButton");
        enter.Click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line of code is line 577?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have  now added what lines those are in the snippets.. Sorry about that.

Comment: The error message says line 577, not 557.  In any case, if that's the line that's throwing, then `userId` is the culprit, not `loginPage`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry I meant to type 577.

Comment: No worries. ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, I am assuming that the value of userId is null meaning that _driver.GetElementByCssSelector("#username"); isnt giving me anything?

Comment: That would be my guess, yes.